# boost::serialization stack corrupted for text_oarchive object

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I wanted to setup a quick serialization of some objects for debuging purposes using boost::serialization.

I have tested the the below function with success in a simple standalone Win32 console application (32bit and 64bit) and it worked as expected.

Using the function in my main Visual Studio Solution (64bit) I get "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'oa' was corrupted."
when leaving the function. The created file looks ok or as expected but the application crashes.
First I thought this happened cause I have not closed the `ofstream`, but this does not help.

I am trying to archive a simple matrix structure implented in `QuantLib`, I leave the details cause the error message is about the text_oarchive object.

```
void saveMatrix(const Matrix &m, const char* fileName){
    ofstream file(fileName);
    text_oarchive oa(file);
    oa << m.rows() << m.columns();
    for (Matrix::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
        oa << *it;
    file.close();
}
```

I have tried the same test calling code in the application/solution and in the test project

```
        Matrix m(2, 3, 0);
        m[0][0] = 2.3;  m[0][1] = 1.2;  m[0][2] = 22;
        m[1][0] = 7.3;  m[1][1] = 8.2;  m[1][2] = 8.22;
        saveMatrix(m, "testArchive.txt");
```

In the first one i get the corrupted stack, in the test project it worked.

Comment: I'd say you're linking conflicting ABIs. It's hard to tell from here but check the differences in target settings (Debug/Release, Architecture (32/64 bit), Exception Handling etc., shared library/static runtime)

Comment: sehe, you are right, Mixed up different boost versions in the Projects of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is different versions of boost in the included headers and used libraries (1.61, 1.59). My mistake.

Correcting the properties of the VS Projects the code worked as expected.
Thanks for your hint sehe.

Comment: Cheers. +1 for posting the finding.